# What is Leona's Secret Passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

While I was aware of the **Inverse Ninja Law** reducing the base HP of Akali / Kennen / Shen when present on the same team, I have recently discovered that they are not the only such champions to have a "Secret Passive".

Nidalee, Cougar that she is, grants <strike>younger men</strike> lower level champions 5 bonus XP when she levels up. [Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_Passive#cite_note-1)

In addition, [scuttlebutt](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=965952) says that Leona has a hidden passive as well.

Can anyone spill the beans ?

Comment: Huh, I just learned something new.

Comment: What about Gangplank/Miss Fortune? They have those pirate (hunter) passive effects, or are they just flavor?

Comment: @Grace - the first link indicates that they are merely flavor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sunlight:  Leona's passive  Sunlight deals one less damage to champion skins wearing sunglasses (eg. Surfer Singed and the Commando skins).

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hidden_passive

[Here](http://pastebin.com/GFw1J6ME) is a link to the LOL files, where the information of the wiki comes.

Another source, is a video of Rift Myths:

NOTE: There is a bug in Jarvan's Commando skin and he do not receive less damage.

Comment: Do you have a better source than the wikia? Not to rain on your parade, but Kaze's answer has been linking to the same page for over a month, and I've yet to see conclusive evidence *proving* this to be true (though it certainly seems plausible).

Comment: It is my only source unfortunately. I guess we will have to wait till it is confirmed elsewhere :)

Answer (score 4):

As of this writing, so far, there've been only theories/rumors about Leona's passive. I'm also waiting for a confirmation.

Phreak did give a [hint](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1083939&highlight=leona+secret+passive&page=2):

```
Some Demacian champions are affected.
```

Some claims include, but are not limited to the ff. (I'm still waiting for confirmation for any of them):

- *Unconfirmed but close*: She deals 1 less damage against Demacian champions with Commando skins (sunglasses). See [this thread](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1090468).
- *Confirmed but debunked*: Her `W` breaking Banshee's shield even before it explodes, and revealing herself to enemy units even when she's in bushes or within the fog of war (see screenshots [here](http://i246.photobucket.com/albums/gg95/xxpyromancerxx/LoL/LeonaBrush1.jpg) and [here](http://i246.photobucket.com/albums/gg95/xxpyromancerxx/LoL/LeonaDazzle1.jpg)). This can be explained by looking further into the mechanics of the spell.

Here are other theories, but most of them are unconfirmed:

- Slightly increased Sight Range(Her or Allies) Dance can cause damage
- Miss Chance when facing her
- Her Shield of Daybreak(`Q`) might give a small sight into a nearby bush
- She gets miniscule buffs/debuffs depending on what map is used, e.g. Summoner's Rift Summer/Autumn
- She gains a miniscule buff when laning with Pantheon

Of course, there's the slight possibility that we've been trolled.

Comment: Looks like it was solved in the linked thread.  The -1 dmg is only from her passive, sunlight.