# What are Zyra's 3 hidden passives?

Tags: league-of-legends

Similar to how [Leona has a hidden passive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/what-is-leonas-secret-passive) that reduces her damage to champions that have sunglasses, Zyra apparently has three hidden passives according to one of her designers ([CertainlyT](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/CertainlyT)).

What are Zyra's hidden passives?

[Source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=27368386#27368386):

> Has no one found any of her three hidden passives yet?

Comment: The passives have been found recently, here is the reddit thread about it: http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/xbx8t/zyras_hidden_passives_found/

the first comment is about an video proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Credit goes to SantaInDisguise for finding and confirming these hidden
>   passives. Give that guy a round of applause :] Also, these hidden
>   passives can ONLY be seen in the PBE Client. This means they are NOT
>   yet active on the NA or any other region server. The three passives
>   are written below in detail. Enjoy!

- **Passive #1**: Maokai gains +1 movement speed when within about 500 units of an allied Zyra. This 'boost' will expire about two seconds after he walks away. Maokai will not receive this boost from an enemy Zyra.
- **Passive #2**: Leona's passive, Sunlight, will cause an enemy Zyra's model to grow slightly upon connecting. This growth lasts 20 seconds and does not stack.
- **Passive #3**: When Sion kills Zyra [or Zyra kills Sion], the killer will receive a bonus +2 gold. This is a reference to the Plants Vs. Zombies franchise.

Comment: I didn't see it in the video, so I'm assuming no, but... Does Zyra's size increase from Leona grant her any buffs, or is it *just* a size increase?

Comment: I believe it is just a size increase

Answer (score 14):

There's a [thread about this](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2397274) on the official forums now.  Here's what they say:

- Zyra gains 1 hp/5 seconds when she is near a friendly Leona.  Photosynthesis!
- Yorick's ghouls will only target plants if they're in range instead of targeting champions (different from their minion targeting behavior).  Plants vs Zombies!
- Maokai gains 1 movespeed when he is near Zyra.

See also: [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/x5dia/zyras_hidden_passives_unfinished/).

Comment: Zyra gains 1 hp/5, or Leona? Ambiguous pronouns! I don't think it's true, to boot.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It is slightly ambiguous but usually the plant is the one who benefits growth from photosynthesis ;)

Comment: @RavenDreamer good call, I've reworded it slightly.

Comment: It looks like the Yorick Ghoul thing was proven false according to reddit and the league of legends forums.

Comment: Is the 1hp/5 thing confirmed false also?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I believe that came from this http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/wk6mi/photosynthesis_hidden_passive_idea_for_zyra/ thread, here they say it was just a suggestion on what it should be http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/xbx8t/zyras_hidden_passives_found/c5l0fci. I'll wrangle one of my friends into testing it for confirmation in a bit.

Comment: Do you mean she GAINS 1maxhp/5s or that she is healed for 1hp every 5 secs ?